# How to output different content of page on different places in my template

Tags: pages, shortcode, templates

I have a special template for my homepage. There are many different boxes, and in every box I want to have different content. That should be possible to create over the backends page edit function.

In detail: I want the author to go to the Edit Page panel and enter something like this:

```
[box_1]Content of first box[/box_1]
[box_2]Content of second box[/box_2]
...
```

You get it. And in the pagetemplate-homepage.php I want to something like

```
<div class="box box_1"><?php echo do_shortcode( '[box_1]' ) ?></div>
<div class="box box_1"><?php echo do_shortcode( '[box_2]' ) ?></div>
```

Understand? I just want to split the content of the author input into several sections of my template. The above method doesnt work.
How is to achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `do_shortcode()` only works with shortcodes registered via the Shortcode API: http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: I would consider looking at using a plugin like Advanced Custom Fields to make the development and your UX cleaner http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

Comment: also, when calling `do_shortcode`, exclude the square brackets.  So: `<?php echo do_shortcode( 'box_1' ) ?>`